# Transcendental Numbers (simple question)

Tags: transcendental-numbers

Are all transcendental numbers irrational? I know that not all irrationals are transcendental (for example, $\sqrt{2}$); but I only know of a few transcendental numbers and they are all irrational.

Comment: Yes, of course: a rational number is a root of a polynomial with integer coefficients; for $a/b$ you can use $bx-a$.

Comment: @egreg If you turn that into an answer (and tie into the definition of transcendental), I'll upvote...

Comment: I am surprised that this question had not been asked before  here.

Comment: Perhaps because it usually pops up in algebraic number theory or in fields extensions and then it is really trivial @Lost1? And who knows: perhaps the question's been asked before...

Comment: @DonAntonio for me, google is better resource for this type of thing, which, of course, often returns a math.se link anyway?

Comment: Strangely, this question HAS been asked before, but the cabal of moderators here keep shifting things around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compile what has been said above, any transcendental number must be irrational.
As [egreg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/62967/egreg) mentions, it suffices to use the polynomial $p(x) = bx-a$ for any rational number $a/b$. Note the definition of "transcendental:" A number is transcendental if it is not the root of any nonzero polynomial with rational coefficients. Hence we have shown that indeed any rational number is *algebraic,* that is, not transcendental.